# updation of SQLite database not working

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to update Userdetail table  in SQLite database using XCode 4.3.2. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)saveUserProfile
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [mDatabasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mDiary) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                               @"UPDATE USERDETAIL SET mUname = \"%@\", mGender = '%@', mEmail = \"%@\", mAddress = \"%@\", mLatitude = \"%@\", mLongitude = \"%@\" WHERE mUserName = \"%@\" ", mUname.text, mGender.text, mEmail.text, mAddress.text, mLatitude.text,mLongitude.text, mUserName];
        const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(mDiary, update_stmt, 
                           -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE){

            mStatus.text = @"Failed to update user profile";
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(mDiary);
    }
}
```

The table is not geting updated. What is the problem?

Comment: print the string updateSQL and check the query

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Objective C. Should I use NSLog to do it? Because if I write NSLog(@"%@",updateSQL); I get an error: Use of undeclared identifier updateSQL. I also made a slight change to the query. I modified '%@' after mGender to \"%@\".

Comment: ya after  NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: 
                               @"UPDATE USERDETAIL SET mUname = \"%@\", mGender = '%@', mEmail = \"%@\", mAddress = \"%@\", mLatitude = \"%@\", mLongitude = \"%@\" WHERE mUserName = \"%@\" ", mUname.text, mGender.text, mEmail.text, mAddress.text, mLatitude.text,mLongitude.text, mUserName];
         this write nslog

Comment: If you're using SQLiteManager (from Firefox) or any other SQLite tool then first execute that query directly there! If it would be updating the table then the problem may be with your code!